# How to set default value of variable in live template in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

There could be a little misunterstanding in live templates in Intellij IDEA. I mean default values for variables in templates.

Suppose we have this live template

[image]
[image]

What I expect here, that when calling this template (type *jqon* and press *TAB*) I will see default values already typed which I can change or leave as it is. Like this

[image]

But no. I have empty strings instead of default values

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I was wrong about *Default value* field. I don't need this in my case. I need to fill *Expression* field.

If I want just paste some string as default value I should put this string in quote in *Expression*. So now my variable settings look this way

[image]

And everything works how I want!

Comment: That is the reply I sent you to the support mail =)

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yep, I stole your answer :)

Comment: @CrazyCoder what's the use for the "Default value" field then?

Comment: @Flatline you can find it in [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/edit-template-variables-dialog.html).

Comment: Thanks!. imho this is very bad UX. `default value` should behave like this

Comment: Double quoted string in "Expression" field works as you wanted also but "Default value" field is the right place for that purpose. All you needed were double quotes.

Answer (score 49):

If you want a hardcoded string as the default value field (in the edit  variables dialog), it needs to be in double quotes ("ii"). Putting a string there with no quotes (ii) does not result in an error, but also does not work.