# Is Tab Insertion of Sublime Text 2 available in IntelliJ? If yes, how can one use it?

Tags: intellij-idea, sublimetext2

In the first 3 minutes of [this video](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/your-first-snippet/) a useful feature of Sublime Text 2 is described: **tab insertion**. I wonder if such a feature is available in IntelliJ IDEA, if yes, how can one use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! In all JetBrains IDE's this feature have name as **Live Templates**. Check this [article](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/10/high-speed-coding-with-custom-live-templates/) where you can find the same screencast about snippets. Also visit this [blog post](http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2014/01/14/code-faster-with-intellij-idea-live-templates/).

Be useful similar questions:

- [How to set default value of variable in live template in Intellij IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14015108/2650174)
- [Intellij Live Template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6097646/2650174)